# Redirect user once using iptables

Tags: iptables, raspberry-pi, wifi-hotspot, access-point

I have an access point (Raspberry Pi) running Raspbian (Debian). I need it to redirect user visiting specific website to another one, but only when the user visits the first site for the first time. I think I already figured out how to do redirecting via iptables, but I need it to happen only once for each user.

Comment: Does the website have to be initially blocked no matter what the user does, or do you just want to redirect the user if they connect normally? Is it HTTP or HTTPS? What should happen if there are multiple websites at the same IP address?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if this is for a prank, then a contrived hack might work: use the LOG target of iptables to log each redirect match before actually doing the redirect. Then have a script that extracts the IP from the log and prepends them to the iptables chain, with a RETURN action or something so that the redirect rules aren't reached.

I don't think this problem can be solved robustly at the level of iptables.